# Wildfly 9 - How do I add jvm arguments to individual servers

Tags: wildfly, high-availability

I'm in the process of configuring a HA Wildfly cluster for session replication and I'm having trouble figuring out how to add JVM arguments to the individual servers in the domain.  The arguments I add in domain.conf are applied to the process controller but not the individual servers.  I can change the heap size for the server groups in domain.xml:

[image]

but I'm having trouble adding other arguments.  Can I use this jvm section to add any argument?  Is there another way to add arguments to server groups?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `jvm-options` attribute on in CLI or you really want to edit the XML you can use `<jvm-options/>`.

CLI Example:

```
/server-group=main-server-group/jvm=default:write-attribute(name=jvm-options, value=["-XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError", "-XX:+UseCompressedOops"])
```

XML Example:

```xml
<server-group name="main-server-group" profile="full">
    <jvm name="default">
        <heap size="64m" max-size="512m"/>
        <jvm-options>
            <option value="-XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"/>
            <option value="-XX:+UseCompressedOops"/>
        </jvm-options>
    </jvm>
    <socket-binding-group ref="full-sockets"/>
</server-group>
```

You can also define them at the server level if you need some setting only on a single server in the server group. See the `host.xml` for an example of that.